# RegEx to remove characters from XML (XML is being returned funky)

Tags: c#, xml, regex

I'm using a Universe database to retrieve some XML from a file, and for some reason it's returning it as such:

```
<RESPONSE InternalAccountIdentifier=\"ZZMTGBLDR\" />
```

I need to remove the "\"'s after the "=" and before the closing quote. This is the xml that is actually returned, that I need to parse!

Can anyone help me write a Regular Expression so that I can replace all instances of that and have clean values for the attributes?

I'm completely new to Regular Expressions, and don't completely understand how to write them. I've been trying to do xml.Replace(@"=\", "=") and xml.Replace(@"\"", """) (where xml is my returned xml string)

I can't get that to work though, and was thinking regular expressions would solve my problem.

Comment: Can you edit your post with code you've tried so far so that we can help you with it?

Comment: And please confirm that what you are showing is actual value, not one you see in debugger.

Comment: Alexei, I think you may be correct. I just looked into that, and apparently VS debugger shows back slashes before quotes when viewing strings.

Comment: Did you try to escape the backslash (with an other backslash)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below `c#` code to remove `\` after `=` sign and also the `\` symbols present just before to the closing quotes.

```
string str = @"<RESPONSE InternalAccountIdentifier=\""ZZMTGBLDR\"" /> \""foo bar"" ";
string remove = Regex.Replace(str, @"(""[^""]*)\\""", "$1\"");
string result = Regex.Replace(remove, @"(?<==)\\", "");
Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.ReadLine();
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/CAV1Ix)